# identify outgoing call connect event

Tags: android, phone-call

I am developing an android Application that measures the time taken by the outgoing call from the moment calling starts upto the call actually connects with the target phone ( just when the ring goes on).

for ex: When we dial a call following are the events that occurs:

> 1. outgoing call made   ---> 2. network looks for the target phone( meanwhile we hear beeps ) ---> 3.Ring goes on the target phone ---> 4. target phone picks the call ---> 5.call Ended.

so I need to measure the time between event-1 to event-3.
I can detect the `event 1` through `phoneStateListener` where phonecall state goes to `OffHook`
but Android does not provide any API or method for detecting `event 3`. I also monitor the logcat at theat instant  but find nothing helpfull.
I am stucked in it from last week and reached no where. Please help me in Identifying the event 3.

Comment: Did u got event 3 solutions or not?. Actualy I too searching for that only :(

Comment: Have you got any solution then please share?

Comment: Does not find anything concrete.  But you can check the radio logs generated. That would actually help you determining the event 3 there.